# Eclipse can't find Maven dependency package

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, import, package

In Eclipse, I created a project using Maven and added pdfbox as a dependency. Eclipse automatically rebuilt the project, and I see pdfbox-2.0.11.jar in Maven Dependencies in the package explorer.

However, in my main Java file where I intend to use this:

```
package my.group.project;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
```

Eclipse tells me "The import org cannot be resolved."

What do I do?

My `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>my.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>project</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>invoices</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>10</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>10</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.11</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Are you using the latest jdk10? (10.0.2) If you have jdk 1.8 installed, can you try with that one?

Comment: And what maven version are you using?

Comment: Java SE 10, not sure how to check maven version

Comment: There are several Java SE 10 versions, it could be 10, 10.0.1, or 10.0.2. Run "java -version" on the command. To get the maven version, find the maven directory and then enter "mvn -version" there. This will also tell you the java version.

Comment: Thanks, java: 10.0.2, maven: 10.0.2

Comment: Oh, I misread it, lol! My maven version is 3.5.0.

Comment: 3.5.0 is fine. Next desperate thing to try: go to the maven repository directory (in windows, it is C:\Users\YOURNAME\.m2\repository\org\apache and then delete the pdfbox directory, and then run build (mvn install in the top directory of your project, or through eclipse if eclipse provides this). This would reload the pdfbox libs.

Comment: Got an error on mvn install. https://pastebin.com/ywJWHu08

Comment: "package org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel does not exist" at line 3 is weird - do you have that package declaration in your OWN code? Is your own file properly in the directory …../my/group/project…. ?

Comment: No, my package declaration is definitely correct. Here is line 3:
`import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;`

Comment: Another idea: could it be that there is an invisible character somewhere? To check that, remove the imports and all newlines, then use the keyboard combination of your IDE to fix imports.

Comment: Nope, didn't help. Although, Eclipse suggested I import PDDocument (with the correct qualified name), so I double-clicked that, but I get the same error.

Comment: No further idea from me at this time, sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was something terribly wrong with my project, so I created a new one, added pdfbox as a Maven dependency, copied the Java file over, and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarification: I guess that the particular class is also visible if you extend the contents in the jar in the package browser, isn't it?

If that's the case could you maybe provide your pom.xml?

However, you could also try to clean the project via `Project -> Clean` first.. Eclipse sometimes just behaves weird as you certainly know.

Comment: 1. Yes it is. 2. sure! 3. Thanks, I’ll try that.

Comment: Cleaning didn't help, and I edited in the pom.xml. Welcome to SO, by the way!

Comment: Thanks. ;) So, I built a test project myself using your pom.xml that also imports the PDDocument and for me it worked perfectly fine. Does eclipse point out any build path problems? And which JRE version are you using?

Comment: If nothing of this works you could try to build a new Maven project by importing your pom.xml using the Maven import wizard. That's what I did. After that you could then move your sources from the old to the new project and it should work. Something seems to be corrupted in your project setup.

Comment: No build path problems as far as I can tell, Java SE 10.0.2, deleting project from workspace and importing as Maven project didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

Project --> Properties --> Maven.
Uncheck the box labeled "Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects" --> Apply and Close

Right click on your project --> Maven --> Update Project...
Check the boxes "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases", "Update project configuration from pom.xml", "Clean projects"

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have luck, but for me it worked just close and open the project (right click menu on project)